# Getting distance between Two Locations in android but not working

Tags: android, location, distance, street-address

Actually I want to get exact distance between two lat and lang. But I have tried three different functions but all are not giving me right distance.

Here is Code:

```
 private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {

//first formula
        Location startPoint=new Location("locationA");
        startPoint.setLatitude(lat1);
        startPoint.setLongitude(lon1);

        Location endPoint=new Location("locationA");
        endPoint.setLatitude(lat2);
        endPoint.setLongitude(lon2);

        double distancee=startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint);

// second formula
        float[] results=new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween( lat1,  lon1,  lat2,  lon2, results);
        float result= 0;
        if (results != null) {
            result = results[0];
        }
        double dvar=(double)result;



        //third formula
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1))
                * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
                + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

        return (distancee);
    }


    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

These all are not giving me right distance please guide me how can I perform this goal

Comment: How do you know that it's not the right distance? Is it too big or too small? Or is it close to the right distance? In other words, what's the distance that you get and the distance that you expect?

Comment: I got the distance these two lat and lang online its gave me near 4.1km but these function are giving me 2 km

Comment: I am expecting above 4km but its giving me 2 km

Comment: Do you check the distance online in Google Maps? Because the distance that you are calculating is a raw distance in a straight line, it doesn't account for roads like Google Maps or anything else.

Comment: yes I checked on google maps giving me 5.1 km

Comment: I have checked on google map as  well but google maps giving me 5.1km rather 2km

Comment: yeah, it has to be more in google maps. But google maps has a tool to check the distance in a straight line. Pick your starting point, then right click on the endpoint and select measure distance, you will see a small ruler, drag it between these points and see what you get,

Comment: yes its giving me 2.23km then how can I get exact distance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance that you are getting is a straight line between the two points, and as you found out by using the tool in `GoogleMaps` it is correct. In order to get the distance which takes into account the roads and everything else, you will have to use [Google Directions Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). You will need to make an HTTP Request using [`Retrofit`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [`OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or something else.

In your request, you will need to provide origin and destination and as a response, you will get a bunch of information, including the distance, you can find more info on the docs website that I linked.